# Automatically choosing dropdown option based on previous page click

Tags: html, forms, html-select

We are currently building a request form in html that will allow users to look through a learning catalogue and if they want to apply for it they click the apply button which takes them to a request page and automatically chooses the resource from a drop down to save them having to choose it themselves.

Is there any possible way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: We've not had any luck up until now, we have the catalogue set up and an action button for apply next to it, which will take us to the request page but it just wont automatically select from the drop down menu. Leaves us just with the default selection

Comment: Is it pure HTML + Javascript? Are you not using server side languages (such as ASP.NET, PHP, etc)? Please share some code.

Comment: It's pure HTML & Javascript, no serverside.

I will post code shortly as away from business atm. I'm just looking to really find out if it's possible without serverside languages as I know HTML + Java can be limited.

Comment: It's perfectly possible.